# Unable to get all SAML:Attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, single-sign-on, saml

I am trying to implement SSO using MVC.
Below is a part of my sample SAML that is being generated from my organization's ADFS.

```
<saml:AttributeStatement>
    <saml:Subject>
        <saml:SubjectConfirmation>
            <saml:ConfirmationMethod>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:cm:bearer</saml:ConfirmationMethod>
        </saml:SubjectConfirmation>
    </saml:Subject>
    <saml:Attribute AttributeName="upn" AttributeNamespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims">
        <saml:AttributeValue>SA13245@xyz.com</saml:AttributeValue>
    </saml:Attribute>
    <saml:Attribute AttributeName="emailaddress" AttributeNamespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims">
        <saml:AttributeValue>sanketh.jain@xyz.com</saml:AttributeValue>
    </saml:Attribute>
    <saml:Attribute AttributeName="name" AttributeNamespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims">
        <saml:AttributeValue>Sanketh K Jain</saml:AttributeValue>
    </saml:Attribute>
</saml:AttributeStatement>
```

This is how I am trying to get the 3 attributes:

**Controller**

```
ViewBag.User = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity as Microsoft.IdentityModel.Claims.ClaimsIdentity;
```

**View**

```
@{
    Microsoft.IdentityModel.Claims.ClaimsIdentity user = ViewBag.User;
    <span>@user.Name</span><br />
    foreach(var c in user.Claims)
    {
        <span>@c.ClaimType --- </span>
        <span>@c.Value</span>
        <br />
    }
}
```

Before you ask, I am not using any middle ware, like OWIN. Just a few changes in the Web.config file.
But with this approach, my output only gives me

```
Sanketh K Jain
http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name --- Sanketh K Jain
```

I would like to know why the other claims, such as upn and emailaddress aren't being accessed by the claims. I am fairly certain that there is nothing wrong in the ADFS implementation, but in case there is, please feel free to advice me on a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

In your controller I think you should use the Microsoft.IdentityModel.Claims and in your view, loop throught Claims.

Example for the email address, you can check with : c.ClaimType == ClaimTypes.Email.

Comment: Microsoft.IdentityModel.Claims is a namespace. I cannot loop through that.

Comment: What about the collections Claims ? Have you checked if all the attributes are present ?

Comment: If you're talking about Microsoft.IdentityModel.Claims.ClaimsCollections, then that is null.
All attributes are present where?

Comment: I'm talking about the user.Claims

Comment: While looping through user.Claims, I get:
http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name --- Sanketh K Jain.
Nothing else.

Comment: Then there is just the last attribute "name" of your SSO.

Comment: How can that be? The SAML contains more than 1 attributes

Comment: This is the problem where you only get the last attribute. You need to look at the namespace to find another object who contains all the attributes.

If not,I use to work with the SAML Component Pro library, it works pretty well.